# How to receive output from a random switch statement in Android?

Tags: java, android

I'm creating a simple game of rock-paper-scissors, and I have to receive a random output from Android depending on the number variant I choose (0 = scissors, 1 = rock, 2 = paper).

It's pretty much complete, but I'm receiving no output in either TextView when I type in a number and click the 'shoot' button.

```
package com.example.brandon.rockpaperscissors;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final EditText player = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPlayer);
        final TextView android = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtAndroid);
        final TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtResult);
        Button shoot = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShoot);

        shoot.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                int num = (int)(Math.random() *  (3) + 0);

                switch (num) {

                    //If computer picks scissors
                    case 0:

                        if (player.equals('0')) {

                            android.setText("0!");
                            result.setText("It's a Tie!");

                        } else if (player.equals('1')) {

                            android.setText("0!");
                            result.setText("You Win!");

                        } else if (player.equals('2')) {

                            android.setText("0!");
                            result.setText("Android Wins!");

                        }
                        break;

                    //If computer picks rock
                    case 1:

                        if (player.equals('0')) {

                            android.setText("1!");
                            result.setText("Android Wins!");

                        } else if (player.equals('1')) {

                            android.setText("1!");
                            result.setText("It's a Tie!");

                        } else if (player.equals('2')) {

                            android.setText("1!");
                            result.setText("You Win!");

                        }
                        break;

                    //If computer picks paper
                    case 2:

                        if (player.equals('0')) {

                            android.setText("2!");
                            result.setText("You Win!");

                        } else if (player.equals('1')) {

                            android.setText("2!");
                            result.setText("Android Wins!");

                        } else if (player.equals('2')) {

                            android.setText("2!");
                            result.setText("It's a Tie!");

                        }
                        break;

                }
            }

        });

        }
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Try instead of using "player.equals", use "player.getText().toString().equals"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are comparing the text that the player entered wrongly i.e. here:

```
if (player.equals('0')) {
```

As you can see, `player` is of type `EditText`. So if you compare an `EditText` with a character, it always evaluates to `false` because they are completely different things. I think you actually want to compare the *text* of the edit text with `0`, right? Just like this:

```
if (player.getText().toString().equals("0")) {
```

You can also add in a call to `trim()` so that whitespace characters will be ignored:

```
if (player.getText().toString().trim().equals("0")) {
```

Also, remember to change the other wrong if statements as well.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification on the if statements, it works perfectly! :D

Comment: @Throughout If you think my answer answers you question, please consider accepting it by clicking the green tick below the votes!

Comment: @Sweeper Done! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason you are not getting any output is because the way you retrieve the text from the **Player** `EditText`. The proper way to retrieve the text from an `EditText` is like so:

```
player.getText().toString();
```

Only then you should use the `.equals` like so:

```
player.getText().toString().equals("0")
```

Try it out and tell me if it works. For more info about EditTexts. Check here - [EditText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html).

Answer (score -1):

You're not printing any output. That is the reason why you don't get the output.

Comment: No, I think he means "not getting the text view's text changed". Of course there isn't output in the logcat.

Comment: he isn't implementing command to set updated value of text result to text view.

Comment: And i think a final variable can only be initialized once.